# Getting Concurrent Session Metrics from IIS Raw Logs?

Tags: iis, log-files, logparser

I have IIS 6 and 7 raw log files and the Log Parser tool version 2.2 and I want to find the peak/max concurrent sessions per day that are recorded on the logs for the last 30 days. Is there a quick example of how to do this with Log Parser? Or is there a better alternative approach to create the report using a different tool?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/45516/recommended-logparser-queries-for-iis-monitoring).