# Windows Server traffic monitor that show traffic for each connected IP

Tags: iis, performance-monitoring, web

I would like to see traffic in bytes of individual users (IP's) in real time. Logging would be good too.

Additionally I would like to see which process (CGI.exe, php script etc) they are connected to or minimally what the GET/POST request was.

I have looked at many server monitoring tools but have not found something like this.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look to Microsoft Network Monitor. It's free:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4865

Also another choice would be Wireshark. It's free too.
http://www.wireshark.org/

Answer (score 1):

netstat -ab for connection points.

logparser to find users traffic.
[Recommended LogParser queries for IIS monitoring?](https://serverfault.com/questions/45516/recommended-logparser-queries-for-iis-monitoring)

Comment: Thank you for that. I was hoping for something in real time with a nice UI

Answer (score 0):

tried `Perfmon /res` ?

It's possibly *too* realtime, but does what you're asking for the most part!

Answer (score 0):

For users traffic I'd recommend [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/).  The windows version is not free but it does work very well and it's very close to realtime.

Answer (score 0):

TCPView does most of what you require...

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437

In fact, if the entire SysInternals suite is quite useful in terms of logging on Windows and is quite lightweight as well and deals with networking, security, and other other issues.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795532