# IIS bandwidth Monitoring

Tags: iis, monitoring, bandwidth, microsoft-dynamics-crm

I have a public MS CRM 2011 install and one of my remote users reported using about 10gig of data from their Outlook client.

Is it possible in real time to see connected users in IIS and how much data they are consuming ? (Dedicated server no other users on it)

I don't have access to the external firewall so all monitoring would have to be taken off the local IIS server. Perfmon I think can do this but wanted to see if there where any other ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

John,

You can use Resource Monitor in Server 2008+ to view individual connections in real time.  In Server 2008 R2 (might be the same in Server 2008) there are two tables in the Network tab that are of interest to you: the Network Activity table and the TCP Connections table.

The Network Active table will give you the local application, the PID, the remote address, and the send and received bytes per second.  The TCP Connections will tell you the local address, local port, remote address, remote port, packet loss, latency, and local application/service.

You can consult your IIS logs and see exactly what URLs are being hit (not really real time, but pretty close).  You can also utilize Log Parser to see how much data is sent and received if you configured IIS to log that information.  [IIS.NET](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-iis-performance-issues-or-application-errors-using-logparser) provides a lot of information on different ways to use Log Parser to troubleshoot IIS.  An example of a query to show you total bandwidth by a user (IP/User Agent) is:

```
SELECT TOP 30
c-ip as Client, 
SUBSTR(cs(User-Agent), 0, 70) as Agent, 
Sum(sc-bytes) AS TotalBytes, 
Count(*) as Hits 
FROM {filename} 
group by c-ip, cs(User-Agent) 
ORDER BY TotalBytes desc
```

This query was found. along with more examples, [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/45516/recommended-logparser-queries-for-iis-monitoring)

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell: Install IIS Log Parser v2.2. I created a new directory in drive D called LogParser and copied 2 files (logparser.dll and logparser.exe) into that directory. Now let’s see Powershell codes how to use LogParser v2.2 with Powershell.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Websites = Get-Website *
Foreach ($i in $Websites)
{
$Name = $i.Name
$ID = $i.ID
$PhysicalPath = $i.PhysicalPath
$Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyMMdd") + '.log'
$Bandwidth = &'D:\tools\LogParser\LogParser.exe' "Select Div(Sum(sc-bytes),1048576) As Bandwidth From '$PhysicalPath\W3SVC$ID\u_ex$Date'" -q:ON
$Value = "$Name : $Bandwidth"
Add-Content -Path Bandwidth.txt -Value $Value
}
```