# Track outgoing bandwidth usage of single IIS website on my VPS

Tags: windows-server-2016, bandwidth, performance-monitoring, cdn, iis-10

I want to track OUTGOING bandwidth consumption from a single website in IIS to my site visitors (no internal traffic), e.g. CSS, images, HTML.
The reason is that I want to know which package would be applicable to me when running my website via a CDN provider.
I use IIS10 on Windows Server 2016.

So to clarify: I DON'T want ALL IIS traffic, or ALL my websites in IIS, just a SINGLE website and then only outgoing traffic to my visitors.

I already checked here:

- [IIS bandwidth Monitoring](https://serverfault.com/questions/532819/iis-bandwidth-monitoring)
- https://forums.iis.net/t/1183667.aspx
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/configure-performance-monitoring

I've contacted some paid services, but none of them track on a per site basis.
I've been checking Resource Monitor and Performance Monitor too, but they don't appear to track on a per-site basis either from what I can see.

Answer (score 0):

you could add a new network adapter and bind the new IP-Adress to your site.
After that you can use a traffic monitor for the network-adapter.

but there is probably a lot of effort behind it... Routings, NAT, etc..

Comment: Thanks, I'm no expert so will look further. So strange Microsoft does not offer anything like this by default in IIS.